# how to get the index and textview of the selected item in listview?

Tags: android, web-services, listview

i have a listview from webservice and i want to get the index and textview of the selected item .my list view is

```
         company                  symbol

         android                   an
         iphone                    ip
         blackderry                bb
            .                       .
            .                       .
            .                       .
```

so tell me how to get the index and textview of symbol in the listview from webservice.i used two methods

firstmethod:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position,long id) 
{
        super.onListItemClick( l, v, position, id);

        ID = id;

    int selectedPosition = l.getSelectedItemPosition();
        index=String.valueOf(selectedPosition);
         Log.e("index value","index"+index);

   TextView txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.symboltext);
        TextView temp=(TextView)v;
        txt.setText(temp.getText());
        Log.e("text",txt.toString());
```

}

in above code the logcat shows index is -1 and could not shows the txt.

Second method:

```
    listview.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() 
   {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parentView, View childView, int position, long id) 
    {
      String text = ((TextView)childView.getText()).toString();
      //The above text variable has the text value of selected item
      // position will reflect the index of selected item
    }
   public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parentView) 
   {
   }
});
```

in above method the listview didnt get onclick action. so please tell me how to get the index and textview of the selected item in listview.

Best Regards

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have search many forums but i didn't find answer. so please tell me the URL for that Forum.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. And Check your logcat. It should get you the desired result.

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position,long id) 
{
        super.onListItemClick( l, v, position, id);

        ID = id;

       Log.e("index value","index"+position);
       TextView txt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.symboltext);
       Log.e("text",txt.toString());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a hashmap to put your string to a listview

[this link](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2010/04/custom-listview-android-developer.html?showComment=1366031636474#c8182278740767779834) will help you to understand how hashmap works and how the strings are saved and retrived from it

Answer (score 0):

I was trying something like this, on a `Custom ListView`:

[image]

My scenario was:

To fetch three Objects from Server with `JSONArrayRequest` named as:

```
ID (tvLvDocID)
Title (tvLvDocTitle)
Sub Title (tvLvDocSub Title)
```

`ID` is actually the `ID` of the column of item in MySQL database.

What I did was:

```
listViewDoc.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                                    int myPosition = position;

                                    String id_doc_from_lv = listViewDoc.getItemAtPosition(myPosition).toString();
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ID is : " + id_doc_from_lv, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                }
                            });
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

But My problem was that it was returning `Title` of the `Custom ListView`.
And I wanted only and only the `ID`, which I was also showing in `ListView` above Title. *(Its another story I will later apply `INVISIBLE` property to that `ID`)*.

As I wanted only `ID`. So I did toke help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15517638/5737774):

When I add these lines in my code:

```
String tv_ID_Str= ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvLvDocID)).getText().toString();
```

And call this `tv_ID_Str` as:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ID is : " + tv_ID_Str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Aha! Now I can successfully show `tvLvDocID` and I can retrieve all the information from database on this `ID`.

Final code looks like this:

```
listViewDoc.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                                    int myPosition = position;

                                    String id_doc_from_lv = listViewDoc.getItemAtPosition(myPosition).toString();
                                    // selected item
                                    String tv_ID_Str = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvLvDocID)).getText().toString();

                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ID is : " + tv_ID_Str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            }
                        });
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Purpose of my answer is people like me, who spend lot of time to do this. I hope this will help someone.